Invalid hook call in react-redux provider
I am trying to migrate from Parcel 1.0 to Webpack 4, I am using React 16.14, Node: 18.20, Npm 10.7.
Getting below error when running webpack serve
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See "fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call" for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (http://localhost:1234/index.js:27744:13)
    at useMemo (http://localhost:1234/index.js:39904:21)
    at Provider (http://localhost:1234/1.index.js:116817:75)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:1234/index.js:27823:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:1234/index.js:30502:13)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:1234/index.js:31616:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:1234/index.js:13208:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:1234/index.js:13257:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:1234/index.js:13312:31)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:1234/index.js:36223:7)

Below is the output of npm ls react and npm ls react-dom
├─┬ @emotion/core@10.3.1
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ @emotion/styled@10.3.0
│ ├─┬ @emotion/styled-base@10.3.0
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.19
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/react-hooks@3.7.0
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/react@9.5.0
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ emotion-theming@10.3.0
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.8
│ ├─┬ enzyme-adapter-utils@1.14.2
│ │ ├─┬ airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0
│ │ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-bootstrap@0.32.1
│ ├─┬ prop-types-extra@1.1.1
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-overlays@0.8.3
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-prop-types@0.4.0
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@2.9.0
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ └─┬ uncontrollable@4.1.0
│   └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-date-range@1.4.0
│ ├─┬ react-list@0.8.17
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-datepicker@4.25.0
│ ├─┬ react-onclickoutside@6.13.1
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-popper@2.3.0
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@16.14.0
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-intl@3.12.1
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-redux@7.2.9
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router-config@5.1.1
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@5.3.4
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router@5.3.4
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-select@3.2.0
│ ├─┬ react-input-autosize@3.0.0
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.5
│ │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-table@6.11.5
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-tagsinput@3.20.3
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-test-renderer@16.14.0
│ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
└── react@16.14.0

npm ls react-dom
├─┬ @testing-library/react@9.5.0
│ └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.8
│ └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-bootstrap@0.32.1
│ ├── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-overlays@0.8.3
│ │ └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
│ └─┬ react-transition-group@2.9.0
│   └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
├─┬ react-datepicker@4.25.0
│ ├── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-onclickoutside@6.13.1
│ │ └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
│ └─┬ react-popper@2.3.0
│   └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
├── react-dom@16.14.0
├─┬ react-select@3.2.0
│ ├── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
│ └─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.5
│   └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped
└─┬ react-table@6.11.5
  └── react-dom@16.14.0 deduped

Error is originating from react-redux provider. I have tried with webpack 5 as well. I am getting same issue. I tried to use React 17 as well but still same issue.

